# How to change the display powershell (current path) in the console?

Tags: powershell, command-prompt, prompt

The powershell (like other consoles windows) display the full path of the current folder.

The problem is that this path is often long, and pollutes the screen.

How to configure the powershell to display(prompt) only the current folder? (Keeping integration with other modules like Posh-Git)

[image]

Comment: maybe look here -  http://stackingcode.com/blog/2011/11/05/powershell-prompt

Answer (score 4):

Prompt is defined by function `prompt` in Powershell. But if you just want to change it for posh-git than it should not be hard... Because there it's actually just one line. Unless you modified the module behavior you should find file defining prompt here (change notepad to editor of choice):

```
notepad (Get-Command prompt).ScriptBlock.File
```

Original line:

```
Write-Host($pwd.ProviderPath) -nonewline
```

Modify to:

```
Write-Host(Split-Path -Leaf $pwd.ProviderPath) -nonewline
```

Comment: Took me too long to reach this answer... Thanks!